# AngularJS selectタグのディレクティブで未選択状態が最上位にならない

Tags: javascript, angularjs

セレクトタグのスタイルや簡易的なチェックを共通化するため、ディレクティブにしました。

このとき、未選択状態を項目に入れるため、HTMLにoptionを追加しましたが、
未選択状態が一番上に着てほしいのに、順番が入れ替わってしまいます。

**template html**

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item[labelName] for item in array">
    <option ng-if="!!hasTop" value="">選択してください</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

array は、$resource.query の戻り値です。

「選択してください」を絶えず先頭にするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: 翻訳サイト使って英語サイトにも質問してみました。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453657/angularjs-ng-options-non-choice-is-not-the-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語サイトで回答もらいました。

optionタグにng-ifは使えないようです。

方法としては、

## 1. ngOptionsを自分で書き直す。

## 2. selectにng-ifもしくはng-switchを記述する。

## 3．ng-ifの変わりにng-showを使う。

があります。

ということでした。

情報共有のため記載しておきます。